# Will 1500 URL Redirects in .htaccess affect performance?

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, .htaccess, redirection

I would like to add 1500 URL redirections using `.htaccess` on an Apache server.
Is it a bad idea? Will it decrease the performance significantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably work but it will be difficult to maintain.  Performance will start to take a hit as you increase the number of directives, so if there are patterns in your redirects, you may look to bundle them into a single directive (if you can).

It would be architecturally superior to knock together a quick script that looked up the redirection from a more-maintainable and indexed file format (or preferably a database).